# Nested dictionaries, how to avoid pass by reference?

Tags: python, dictionary

I build through loops a dictionary of nested dictionaries like the following:

```
statistics = {'kpi_0': 0, 'kpi_1': 0}

my_dict = {'0':statistics, '1': statistics, ... }
```

Of course, if I modify one element `my_dict['0']['kpi_0'] += 1` I affect all the elements of `my_dict`.

Is there a simple way to avoid this behavior? E.g., can I save the literal version of `my_dict` and build a `new_dict = dict("""literal version of my_dict""")`?

Comment: You managed to spell the `statistics` variable three different ways!

Comment: You appear to have a couple of typos in your code: statistcs / statisics and two items with the same `'kpi_0'` key. Please fix them.

Comment: I'm sorry for the typos. Fixed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `deepcopy`:

```
>>> from copy import deepcopy
>>> statistics = {'kpi_0': 0, 'kpi_1': 1}
>>> my_dict = {'0': deepcopy(statistics), '1': deepcopy(statistics)}

>>> my_dict
{'1': {'kpi_1': 1, 'kpi_0': 0}, '0': {'kpi_1': 1, 'kpi_0': 0}}
>>> my_dict['1']['kpi_0'] += 1
>>> my_dict
{'1': {'kpi_1': 1, 'kpi_0': 1}, '0': {'kpi_1': 1, 'kpi_0': 0}}
```

And keep in mind you can't have 2 keys with the same name in a dictionary.

Comment: If I used `dict(statistics)`instead of `deepcopy(statistics)` is also fine?

Comment: Further Details: if I create `my_dict` as `{'0':statistics, '1': statistics, ... }` I have same values and same `id()` for all `statistics` objects. If i use `dict()`, `id()` does actually change but values do not! If I use `deepcopy()`, both values and `id()` change. Why does this happen?

Comment: For pepople landing on this topic. Here there is the explanation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html